# xPath: Picking div after h4 with specific text

Tags: html, xpath

I'm new to xPath... just trying to learn it...
How can I use xPath to get the div after the h4?
I'm searching for the H4 containing "Canon" first

```
<div class="print-model-text">
    <h4>Canon</h4>
    <div class="price">From €&nbsp;599,-</div>
    <a class="button button-grey" href="#">Check it out</a>
</div>
```

The xPath I used:

```
//*/text()[. = "Canon"]/following-sibling::div[1]
```

Comment: `//div[h4="Canon"]/div/text()` ? Or if the `div` you're looking for always has the `class="price"` attribute: `//div[@class="price"]/text()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is incorrect, what is happening is that you are looking for a sibling within the `<h4/>` since you are going into `../text()..`

You could use the [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function here.

For example:

```
//h4[contains(text(), "Canon")]/following-sibling::div[1]
```

EDIT: You can also use `.=''` syntax.

To use that syntax remove the `text()` from you original query:

```
//*[. = "Canon"]/following-sibling::div[1]
```

Comment: Awesome, I glad I could help you out! If this answer solves your issue, please feel free to accept it as the answer to your question. Thanks!